# Unable to recover crashed Oracle database

Tags: oracle11g, crash

My database crashed all of a sudden due to VM failure. I managed to start the VM again, but database is not getting up. It was in non archivelog mode and I'm unable to restore it now. It's showing as files corrupted. I have no idea what to do.

Comment: https://www.sqlskills.com/help/accidental-dba/

Comment: I don't think it is possible to answer with such minimal detail. Have you looked at your database logs? Do you see errors on any consoles? What operating system is your VM running?